# C++ : Data structure for fast searching

Tags: c++, data-structures

Following is my scenario:

I have to keep all the 3 byte combinations of the extended ASCII something like this:

```
{ { (a,a,a),(a,a,b),..........(z,z,z) } }
```

All these combination results in a big set of 256*256*256 values

In my algorithm , it happens that after every iteration the big set breaks into something like this:

```
 {(a,a,a), (a,a,b)}
 {(a,a,c)}
.
.
.
.
{(z,z,z)}
```

I am implementing this using vector of set of array.

```
vector<set<array<char,3> > > Partition;
```

the reason behind using this is that a big set will break into subsets .The number of these subsets is not known and after each iteration the number of subsets may increase therefore I am using vector. Then the subset should not contain any element twice therefore I am making use of set and array is used to keep the 3 characters.

The problem in using the above data structure is that it is taking lot of time in computing the results.

I need suggestions regarding a data structure which can be more efficient in my case.

**More explanation of my algorithm:**

```
{(a,a,a),(a,a,b)........ (z,z,z)}
```

All these triplats are keys of an unordered map. All these triplates correspond to a certain value like this

```
(a,a,a)           value=2
(a,a,b)           value=2
(a,a,c)           value=3
(a,a,d)           value=2
.
.
.
.
.
```

Now, I run my algorithm and want to know on the basis of value how much they can be compressed: Like this

```
{(a,a,a) ,(a,a,b)  }          value=2
(a,a,c)                       value=3
{(a,a,d),......}              value=2
```

Why I have to make a separate subset for value=2 because according to my algorithm I have to  make a new set whenever my previous value differs from the present value.

Comment: I hope it's a set of 256*256*256.

Comment: Have you found an answer to your question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well you are caring `3 * 8b` so there is 24bit value. Instead of having `{0, 0, 0}` you can have one integer `0` instead of `{'a', 'a', 'a'}` you can have `0x616161` because `'a' == 0x61`

All these ints can be stored in [std::map](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/) where integer made of 3 symbols is key. Or you can use array `ValueType arr[256*256*256]`. I recommend to use array, however if you have just a few values, you can use map.

To convert from `int` to 3 chars you can use bitwise operations `<<` and `>>` read about them [here](http://www-numi.fnal.gov/offline_software/srt_public_context/WebDocs/Companion/cxx_crib/shift.html) and [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/operators/). But I hope you understand bit shifting.

Comment: Well I don't have much idea about bit shifting, I need to check it.

Comment: Bit shifting allows to take any bit or bits from integer so you always need to take last 8 bits to indicate your letter, but before taking last bits you need to shift your number by 8 or 16 positions. But you should read about it, it's sometimes really useful.

Comment: Sounds like something you'd want to do with a `union`. That way you can address it as a single number, or as individual bytes.

Comment: Well `union` would be the best solution if there would be 4 instead of 3 values and those 3 characters doesn't need to be transmitted into other machine, because because integer index value using `union` depends on endian and may depend on compiler.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just a single array:

```
int[256*256*256] values;
```

Create a union:

```
typedef struct
{
    byte b1;
    byte b2;
    byte b3;
} triplet;

union tIndex
{
    triplet trip;
    int index;
}
```

So if you want to access item `['a','b','c']`, you could write:

```
union tIndex;
iIndex.index = 0;  // make sure all bytes are cleared.
tIndex.b1 = 'a';
tIndex.b2 = 'b';
tIndex.b3 = 'c';
values[tIndex.index] = 22;
```

So imagine you initialize your array with values of -1, or some other value that isn't valid in your application. Then run your calculations that modifies some of the array items.

You can then go through the array sequentially, picking out adjacent items that have the same count, and combining them.

It's difficult to know for sure if that'll work, because I don't have a lot of information about your application. But if you can think of it that way it could save you a lot of trouble manipulating vectors and sets.